# Number of ros_control nodes with a controller_manager (ros1 - noetic)

Tags: ros, ros-control, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently building a robot. The robot has two continuous spinning motors (wheels) and two servos.
I plan on using the `ros_control` stack to control the operators.

In order to enhance have a nice separation between the two types of hardware I would like to have them in separate notes. Each of the nodes should implement `hardware_interface::RobotHW`. Since the hardware interface has to be registered in the `controller_manager` I need a `controller_manager` in both nodes.

Might is cause problems to spawn two instances of the `controller_manager`? Is there anything special to take care of in this case?
Should the whole robot hardware be controlled with a single `ros_control` node or are two nodes preferable (one for each type of hardware used)?

Note: ros-noetic on Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406292/number-of-ros_control-nodes-with-a-controller_manager-(ros1---noetic)/) by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2022-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<del>Apparently it can cause problems when spawning multiple controller_manager instances (multiple nodes which implement the `hardware_interface::RobotHW` interface and a control loop) as discussed [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/issues/265).</del>

A solution to this problem seems to be the combined_robot_hw interface (see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/combined_robot_hw)). A guide how to use the `combined_robot_hw` interface can be found [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki/Writing-CombinedRobotHW).

---

Originally posted by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) with karma: 65 on 2022-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-12**:
You mention you're thinking of using different nodes for each `controller_manager`. That will work, and is a different situation from what is described in the issues you link.

Note that using different nodes immediately makes synchronised motion across all targeted joints impossible.

**Comment by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) on 2022-09-12**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for the hint, I edited my answer.